# Quering Embedded Documents using MongoEngine in django, python

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I need to get all EmbeddedDocuments of type Subject from Document Lesson, where Subject.subject_name = 'Something'.
I am trying to do the following and it's not working for me:

```
results = Lesson.objects.filter(subject__match={'subject.subject_name':'Math'})
```

My models:

```
class Subject(EmbeddedDocument):
    subject_code = IntField()
    subject_name = StringField(max_length=60)
    hours = IntField(required=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.subject_name)

class Lesson(Document):
    subject = EmbeddedDocumentField(Subject)
    teacher = EmbeddedDocumentField(Teacher)
    group = EmbeddedDocumentField(Group)
    room = EmbeddedDocumentField(Room)
    attendance = IntField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.id)
```

Thank you all in advance! 
Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the following link https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/querying.html it becomes obvious, that the **raw** function can solve the task:

It is possible to provide a raw PyMongo query as a query parameter, which will be integrated directly into the query. This is done using the **raw** keyword argument:

```
results = Lesson.objects(__raw__={'subject.subject_name': 'Math'})
```